# sql query for distinct count

Tags: sql

Hi i have a file file1 with data:

```
fld1 fld2  date    fld4
2     abhi 010211   6
2     neha 010211   6
0     xyz  010311   6
0     abc  010211   8
1     ssa  010311   8
1     kiy  010311   8
```

I want a query that gives me for each distinct fld4, count for each distinct fld1 for distinct date . for example i want output like :

for fld4 as 6 it has count=2 for fld1=2 and date=010211,count=1 for fld1=0 and date=010311

Comment: use `count(*)` and `group by columnName` in conjunction with `UNION`.

Comment: i will be thankful to u if you could please provide me the query..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by the fields you mention then count something.

```
Select 
    fld1, 
    date, 
    fld4, 
    count(fld4) as count
from
    Table
group by
    fld1, date, fld4
```